# Is there a way to start the Slack app with a maximised window but still run in the background?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, command-line-arguments, slack

I want to have the Slack desktop application run at startup in the background as it normally does with the *Launch app on login* settings. However this always results in a small sized window when I open slack up by clicking on it's icon afterwards. What I want is the app to open up with a maximised window.

The best solution I've found so far is disabling the *Launch app on login* setting and putting a shortcut to slack in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` and changing the *Run* option from `Normal window` to `Maximised`. But this also starts Slack fully visible on startup, I still want it to run in the background on startup.

I've tried running a .bat file with task scheduler but I can't figure out what to write in it.

Do anyone know if this is possible somehow? Are there any command-line arguments that I can add to the shortcut? Is there some Windows option that I don't know of?

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You may follow these steps:

1. Right click on slack icon in the taskbar
   [slack icon in the taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47Jqf.png)
2. Right click on slack in the menu that pops up
   [slack in menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G92T.png)
3. Left click on properties
   [click on properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cd7w.png)
4. Choose the size that you want
   [slack properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzOOR.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me a question similar to **[that one](https://superuser.com/questions/1510267/i-cant-figure-out-how-to-use-max-command/1510845#1510845)**, anyway, take a look at this option

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && mode 50,03 && title ...\Slack Desktop

set "_Slack=%userprofile%\AppData\Local\slack\slack.exe"
set "_run=%SystemRoot%\System32\CScript.exe" 
set "_vbs=%temp%\ActivFull.vbs" && call type nul >"!_vbs!" 
start "Slack Desktop" /max /realtime "!_Slack" 

set "_run="!_run!" "!_vbs!" //nologo" && set "_pp=%windir%\system32\pathping"
set "_run_it=^>nul del /q /f "!_vbs!" ^& endlocal^&^& exit /b" && >"!_vbs!" (
          echo/ Set objShell=WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
          echo/ objShell.AppActivate "* | Slack"
          echo/ objShell.SendKeys ^("%% "^)
          echo/ WScript.Sleep 00000000150
          echo/ objShell.SendKeys ^("x"^)
          )&& >nul (!_pp!.exe 127.1 -q 1 -p 1500 && >nul !_run! &&!_end_it! )
```

---