# I can't figure out how to use /max command

Tags: batch

So I've been trying to create a batch file on my desktop that starts a file and then opens another file through that file

So far so good only I want the window to be maximized which apparently gets way more complicated

Here's what I got:

```
@echo off
title Pokemon-Ruby Launch
Start C:\Users\groomcha002\Downloads\GPemu.lnk "C:\Users\groomcha002\Downloads\Pokemon-Ruby.gba"
exit
:: MAX?!?
```

Will someone help me in my confusion,
I desperately need that easy access to Pokemon Ruby

Comment: The GPemu shortcut is from Google extension/game?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 64-bit.

How to run a Windows shortcut maximized?

First things first. You forgot the title quotes after start. `Start /?`

```
Start "" "C:\Users\groomcha002\Downloads\GPemu.lnk" "C:\Users\groomcha002\Downloads\Pokemon-Ruby.gba"
```

How to run a shortcut maximized?

Right click shortcut - Properties

[image: screenshot right click shortcut properties]

Run Maximized

[image: screenshot shortcut run maximized]

If that does not work then:

```
Start "" /max "C:\Users\groomcha002\Downloads\GPemu.lnk" "C:\Users\groomcha002\Downloads\Pokemon-Ruby.gba"
```

Answer (score 0):

---

[image]

---

So, this kind of job can't by solved by a simple command in command line, or any settings applied to set **`Proxy_Chrome.exe`** for open it in **full screen**.

You need get a support from others language/script like **[vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs)** or **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**, also, if you look this code, the app is called by **ID**, not by a shortcut, also, there are started by flag **`-new-window`*`app_id`*** in **`Proxy_Chrome`** executable,  you maybe need to edit the variables for put a full qualified path to your **Google**/**Chrome** folder, also to **gba** file. For this answer, I’ve put the **gba** in same folder where the bat/cmd stay/run....

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && mode 50,03 && title ...\GPemu

set "_gext=C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome_proxy.exe"
set "_rom=!cd!\PokemonRuby.gba"&&set "_run=%SystemRoot%\System32\CScript.exe"
set "_id=jhficiigpnhhaojldmanflihieepanbb" && set "_vbs=%temp%\ActivFull.vbs"
type nul >"!_vbs!"&& set "_open_rom_f= --app-id=!_id! --new-window "!_rom!" "
start ".\GPemu" /realtime "!_gext!" --profile-directory=Default !_open_rom_f!

set "_run="!_run!" "!_vbs!" //nologo" && set "_pp=%windir%\system32\pathping"
set "_run_it=^>nul del /q /f "!_vbs!" ^& endlocal^&^& exit /b" && >"!_vbs!" (
          echo/ Set objShell=WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
          echo/ objShell.AppActivate "gametime-palyer"
          echo/ objShell.SendKeys ^("%% "^)
          echo/ WScript.Sleep 00000000150
          echo/ objShell.SendKeys ^("x"^)
          )&& >nul (!_pp!.exe 127.1 -q 1 -p 1500 && >nul !_run! &&!_end_it! )
```

---

> - :: VBS code with no escaping :: 
>     
>
>   ---

```bat
Set objShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.AppActivate "gametime-palyer"
objShell.SendKeys ("% ")
WScript.Sleep 150
objShell.SendKeys ("x")
```

---

The **[vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs)** set to active the GPemu (**`AppActivate`**) and after, will send keys (**`SendKeys`**) to do the maximize the Windows.

---

<sub>So sorry my limited **English**!</sub>